# What swing component is this?

Tags: java, swing

Wondering what is the swing component marked with the arrow or could it be a custom widget implementation ?

[image]

Comment: It could be `JPanel` or even `JLabel` with appropriate styles (background, margins, etc.)

Comment: Looks like a titled border, but with a different LaF.

Comment: @crozin Thanks, Ill have a close look at the styles for JLabel and JPanel

Comment: @JakubZaverka The LaF is nimbus, it looks much the same in all the LaF's  Ill have a look for the titled border, thanks

Comment: That cannot be a titled border - the title usually goes "on" the border not inside it. It could be two `JPanel`'s aligned vertically to form a custom component where the top one would contain a `JLabel` for the title. The LAF looks like `Nimbus`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source code for SwingSet3 is available online.  Looking at the [`GridBagLayoutDemo`](http://java.net/projects/swingset3/sources/svn/content/trunk/SwingSet3/src/com/sun/swingset3/demos/gridbaglayout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java?rev=219) class, you can see that the component is a `JFrame`.